# Height issue with IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

I am not sure what is going on here but for some reason the top portion of my footer is getting twice the necessary height when rendered in IE6.  I have posted an example at https://www.msu.edu/~grossm51/sample/test.html  .  Any insight would be a huge help.

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: Include your html here, not just a link.

Comment: How useless is this question going to be once your sample page is gone?

Comment: I've thought about this actually.  I can't realistically put all the css that might be affecting this here.  I'll do my best to add what I think is relevant to my post however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you've got an element wrapping to a new line. Try reducing or hiding the divs inside `#footerTop` until you figure out which element is causing it.

I would also try taking the border off `#footerTop` and see if that fixes it since you have `width:100%;` specified on that div.

Comment: hiding the top right portion of the #footerTop div collapses the height to where I want it but then I can't seem to get things displaying the way I want and still have the blue on the right side...

Comment: Is it the border issue? Try reducing the width of the center and right divs by 1 or two pixels.

Comment: The border was not the issue.  I was able to hide the upper right div, set the background color of the top center div to the same color the right div was, and set padding-right: 35px; on the top center div.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you didn't insert height value of the element (probably div) below image.

Comment: The element below the image is not the issue I've tried with it set and without with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

If you download the Microsoft IE developers toolbar you can make changes while you are viewing the page, that way you can see what works.

Comment: I am aware of this, I have tried everything that I can think of but I can't seem to get it looking the way I want it to.